# How to speak skype user with the bot using skype calling feature?

Tags: bots, skype, botframework, botconnector

I am working on bot technology, in my current bot project I used the skype calling feature in that I want the functionality like once bot accepted the call after that whatever I spoken with bot I want that speech in my code in the form of text.

Before posted question here I did research on google and find the below link but this link contains dial pad options but I want the functionality like instead of dial pad, I am able to speak with bot and get the that speech into my code in the form of text.

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/calling.html

Can you please tell me how to do that?

-Pradeep

Comment: Look up "speech synthesis" or "speech recognition".

Comment: Thanks, for my scenario I am able tell choices to bot using my voice but I want without choice options. like user to bot conversation similarly two users talk each other.

Comment: Is it possible in skype calling feature with bot, like what ever I speak with bot those speech will automatically converted to text and then those text given to LUIS for identifying the Intents in the speech.

Comment: What I would like to is to call to Bot by skype call then analyse speech, analyse it by Luis and/or Bot Framework then reply to user by text to Speech.

Is it a reasonable scenario? Is it the way or is there another solution?

Comment: are you using C# or Node SDK for BotBuilder?

Comment: I used C# SDK for Bot Builder.

Comment: @pradeep I guess the "dial pad" example you're talking about is the IVR Bot example. You can use that example, keep the part where he records the user to receive a voice message, send the received audio to a speech recognition service and then process the text normally.